# storing a range of latitude and longitudes for one location in mysql

Tags: mysql, google-maps, heatmap

I am experimenting with heat maps using the `Maps JavaScript API`.

The API as it stands hardcodes the data points like this.

```
function getPoints() {
    return [
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.783791, -122.398998),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.784177, -122.398959),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.784388, -122.398971),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.784404, -122.399128),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.784586, -122.399524),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.784835, -122.399927),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.785116, -122.400307)
    ];
}
```

Obviously this method can get untidy If I have a long street with 150 data points. I want to instead persist these data point for the heatmap onto `mysql`.

But more specifically, How would I store a *range* of latitude and longitude coordinates to ***one*** location in `mysql`.

Example:

Howard Street in San Francisco has 150 data points with a range of say (37.783791, -122.398998) TO (37.785116, -122.400307)

How might I set that up within the confines of `mysql`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create two tables in MySQL, one for street and one to store all data points for each street.

For example:

```
create table street (
  id int,
  name varchar(50)
);

create table data_point (
  id int,
  street_id int,
  latitude double,
  longitude double,
  constraint fk1 foreign key (street_id) references street (id)
);
```

Comment: Thanks, However is there a method to do it without having to input say 150 separate data points manually in the data_point table or is there really now away around this

Comment: From the point of view of MySQL there's no automatic way of doing it. It would be up to the API you are using to offer extra automation.